# Не выполняется mysqli->query запрос с условием WHERE

Tags: mysqli

Есть код:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'admin', 'test');

echo $sql1 = " SELECT postal_code FROM location ";
echo $sql2 = " SELECT postal_code FROM location WHERE city_name='Донецк' ";

$result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);

echo ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) ? $row1['postal_code'] : "Запрос ничего не вернул!!!!";
echo "sql1 - кол-во строк - " . $result1->num_rows;

echo ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) ? $row2['postal_code'] : "Запрос ничего не вернул!!!!";
echo "sql2 - кол-во строк - " . $result2->num_rows;
```

В браузере выводится следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если данны запрос копипастом вставить в PMA и выполнить, тогда строка возвращается. Т.е. проблем с кодировками нет. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Почему из php не выполняется запрос `$sql2 = " SELECT postal_code FROM location WHERE city_name='Донецк' ";`

Comment: А если прям в этом запросе вместо `$city_name` написать слово, то вернет что-то?  Если да - дело в переменной, если нет......... в mysqli_error что-то есть?

Comment: Есть написать вручную слово, всё равно ничего не выводится. 
$mysqli->error тоже ничего не выводит.

Comment: нужно больше тогда когда, до запроса, после запроса. структура таблицы. точно ли там есть колонка city_name и пр....может дело в кодировках. как бд, таблиц так и файла.

Comment: А если например в PMA выполнить запрос с WHERE - результат будет? А если будет и теперь точно тот же запрос перенести (через Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V) в программу? city_name на кириллице задаётся? А если варианты с латиницей попробовать? Возможно дело в кодировке.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, если латиницей, тогда всё нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш код:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
$mysqli->query($mysqli, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

перед вызовом `SELECT`. Если в базе у вас данные не в UTF - подставьте ваши значения. Глянуть их можете через PMA.

Answer (score 0):

Как на счет того, чтобы исправить это:

`city_name = '$city_name'`

На вот это:

`city_name = "'.$city_name.'"`

Насколько я знаю, переменная в одинарных кавычках не обрабатывается...

Я бы писал так:

`$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT postal_code FROM location WHERE city_name = "'.$city_name.'"');`

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже не работает почему-то

Comment: @tirael8 странно, а без условия выводит точно? Предоставьте больше кода для размышлений. Что в браузере происходит после выполнения кода? Показ всех ошибок включен?

Comment: @DmitryPotter `переменная в одинарных кавычках не обрабатывается` - она бы не обрабатывалась, если непосредственно весь запрос был бы в одинарных кавычках. А так одинарная кавычка является всего лишь частью строки и никак не влияет на переменную.....в результате ваш нижний запрос аналогичен запросу автора

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с кодировками. Латинскими символами всё удачно выполняется.